# bash, Good practice wanted on how to make the variable of a bash script available to another bash script?

Tags: bash, variables

It is known that it is possible to make common variables used by several scripts available to each other by storing them in a common file.

The exchange of variable values between several scripts via a file on a hard disk, in contrast to an exchange via a variable held in RAM, leads to frequent write operations on a corresponding hard disk.

Software implementation of known way:

```
# write a var to a file
echo "var_01=Alfa" > var_file.sh

# set a new value to a var
sed -i 's/var_01=Alfa/var_01=Berta/' var_file.sh

# delete the value of a var and the var
sed -i 's/var_01=Alfa/""/' var_file.sh

# make a var readable to a script by Include var_file.sh
source ./var_file.sh
```

What would be a better practice, how to make a variable of a bash script, available to another bash script ?

Remark:
Searched are:

- A way to use variales by more than one bash scrip without to need a helper file for the vars which need to store the actual value of the var on a file. It can be its possible to do on RAM, pe. by a not type of variale, perhaps a global var or a envirement var or so on.

Comment: If the _other script_ is a (direct or indirect) child process of the current one, you can put the variable into the environment.

Comment: @user1934428 although using Environment variables has some limitations like not supporting any kind of array or variable flags used by Bash. The only way to persist and preserve those and all the attributes flags is by writing the output of `declare -p` into a file, and importing the file to reload its declarations.

Comment: @LéaGris : Using other means (such as going via a file) also supports only a text stream. If you want to pass typed data, you would have to use a transfer format (JSON, YAML or what else). In the end, `declare -p` **is** producing such a format and if you `source` the file afterwards means parsing it.

Answer (score 4):

With bash, use the `declare` keyword to reliably (properly quote or escape special characters) save variable to file, even if it contains spaces or any special characters.

Eventually you can incorporate a `save_vars` function into the `var_file.sh` that you share with all your other scripts, to save and recover/share variables.

`var_file.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Check file is sourced from a bash script or exit with error
if [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ] || ! (return 0 2>/dev/null); then
  printf 'This %s file is meant to be sourced by a Bash Script\n' "$0" >&2
  exit 1
fi

# Function to save itself and variable names in arguments
# into the current file
# (here it is var_file.sh but could be whatever it is named)
save_vars() {
  # save variables file
  {
    # Write self shebang and usage error handling
    cat <<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ] || ! (return 0 2>/dev/null); then
  printf 'This %s file is meant to be sourced by a Bash Script\n' "$0" >&2
  exit 1
fi

EOF

    # Save itself "${FUNCNAME[0]}" is the name of
    # the current function here it is save_vars
    declare -f "${FUNCNAME[0]}"

    # Save variable names passed as arguments
    declare -p "$@"

    # Into itself file (self-modify or update)
  } >"${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" 2>/dev/null
}
```

`script1`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# load variables or exit with failure
. var_file.sh || exit 1

printf 'Hello I am %s\n' "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"

# Assign value even with spaces and special chars
var_01=$'Alfa Beta Gamma \317\206'
var_02='Something with
a newline'

# Invoke the save_vars function that was imported
# from var_file.sh to save var_01 and var_02
save_vars var_01 var_02
```

`script2`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# load variables or exit with failure
. var_file.sh || exit 1

printf 'Hello I am %s\n' "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
printf 'var_01 contains: %q\n' "$var_01"
printf 'var_02 contains: %q\n' "$var_02"

# set a new value to a var
var_01='Berta'

# delete var_02
unset var_02

# Invoke the save_vars function that was imported
# from var_file.sh to save var_01 only
# (var_02 does not need to be saved since it is deleted
# it will be removed/gone from the save)
save_vars var_01
```

`script3`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# load variables or exit with failure
. var_file.sh || exit 1

printf 'Hello I am %s\n' "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
printf 'var_01 contains: %q\n' "$var_01"
printf 'var_02 contains: %q\n' "$var_02"
```

Comment: `2 > /dev/null` should be `2> /dev/null`

Comment: @Alfred.37 I have updated genericised and commented more the different scripts. I suggest you save them all and play with them, then change them and see what it does if you do this or that with it. It will help understanding how it all works.

Comment: @Léa Gris, If I delete the a empty first line on var_file.sh by a Linux editor, save the fiel and reopen the file by Linux editor, no empty first line exist. After running scrit1 or script2, the var_file.sh have a empty line before #!/usr/bin/env bash. One othe thing is, a part of the code on var_file.sh are double and double by self by running script1 and script2 if I delete this double code on var_file.sh.

Comment: @Alfred.37 then check there is no blank line between the `cat` here-document start `cat <<'EOF'`, and the shebang line within the here-document body: `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. A here-document immediately starts at the next line after a `<<MARKER`.